# Channel Entry link to external URL

Tags: channel-entries

I have a need for a "blog/news" section that has some entries that go from the index to a standard entry blog template, and some that just link to an outside site from the index template. Does EE have a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'd do is set up a field (eg `blog_offsite_url`) to store an optional offsite URL.

Then in your link from the blog index page, use a conditional like this.

```
{if blog_offsite_url}
    <a href="{blog_offsite_url}">More</a>
{if:else}
    <a href="/blog/post/{url_title}">More</a>
{/if}
```

To be thorough, you should put a conditional in the detail template (in this case `blog/post`) to redirect the user to the offsite blog URL when that has been provided.

I like using rsan's [HTTP Header](https://github.com/rsanchez/http_header) plugin for that.

```
{if blog_offsite_url}
    {exp:http_header status="301" location="{offssite_blog_url}" terminate="yes"}
{/if}
```